# Util to get dates for a year

Tags: java

I have a table where I would like each row to be represented as a date along with some other columns to represent the characteristic of that particular date. So, basically I would be having 365 rows for a year. I need to write a batch job in Java, which I would trigger through a rest endpoint. I would pass a particular year to the controller (eg 2020). I would then want **a method which would get me all 366 days (since 2020 is a leap year) for 2020 along with the days i.e. weekends (Sat/Sun) or weekdays (Mon-Fri).**

I would later do a batch insert into DB of those 366 days.

[image]

Can someone help me write this utility method.

Comment: 2020 has 36**6** days... Have you considered leap years? What have you tried so far (in Java)? Can you show us?

Comment: I have updated my question and changed it to 366. On a lighter note, I had used it just for an example and same applies for the table I have attached. Please do not go by the data in it, just a dummy. Yes, I would be having 365 days for non leap and 366 for leap.

Comment: No, I do not have any idea on that particular utility method. I can show you the controller and the rest of the JDBC batch upload code but not sure if that would be of any help. Any help with any APIs or any thing would be appreciated

Comment: How would the signature of your utility method look? Somehow like `public List<LocalDate> getDaysOfYear(int year)`?

Comment: That looks okay, will the LocalDate have the type of date (Weekend/Weeday)? and would I be able to extract it so that I can store that value in a different column in the DB?

Comment: Yes, you are... You can extract the day of week, the month, the corresponding calendar week and so on... `java.time` is worth a look because it is the modern built-in date and time API of Java.

Comment: Sure, I will check that. In that case, the signature you shared should be good to go with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To receive a list of dates of a given year, you can create a method like the following one using `java.time`:

```
public static List<LocalDate> getDaysOfYear(int year) {
    // initialize a list of LocalDate
    List<LocalDate> yearDates = new ArrayList<>();
    /*
     * create a year object from the argument
     * to reliably get the amount of days that year has
     */
    Year thatYear = Year.of(year);
    // then just add a LocalDate per day of that year to the list
    for (int dayOfYear = 1; dayOfYear <= thatYear.length(); dayOfYear++) {
        yearDates.add(LocalDate.ofYearDay(year, dayOfYear));
    }
    // and return the list
    return yearDates;
}
```

You can use the result in order to extract information about each day (in a `main` for example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // receive the LocalDates of a given year
    List<LocalDate> yearDates = getDaysOfYear(2020);
    // define a locale for output (language, formats and so on)
    Locale localeToBeUsed = Locale.US;
    
    // then extract information about each date
    for (LocalDate date : yearDates) {
        // or extract the desired parts, like the day of week
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = date.getDayOfWeek();
        // the month
        Month month = date.getMonth();
        // the calendar week based on a locale (the one of your system here)
        WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(localeToBeUsed);
        int calendarWeek = date.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
        // and print the concatenated information (formatted, depending on the locale)
        System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd",
                                                                    localeToBeUsed))
                + ", " + dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, localeToBeUsed)
                + ", CW " + calendarWeek
                + ", " + month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, localeToBeUsed));
    }
}
```

The output will look like this (just some of the lines for brevity):

```
2020-01-01, Wednesday, CW 1, January
...
2020-02-29, Saturday, CW 9, February
...
2020-05-08, Friday, CW 19, May
...
2020-12-31, Thursday, CW 1, December
```